# Ada - divide a float number and loop over it until it reaches zero

Tags: loops, ada

I need help with this simple iteration problem.  I am trying to divide...

```
vhdl
number : Float := 55.0;

loop 
  number := number / 3.0;
  Put (number);
  exit when number <= 0.0;
end loop;
```

I want it to exit at the first 0.0.

i keep getting infinite loop of

```
18.3   6.1   2.0   0.7   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Tell you what: Take out a piece of paper and divide 3 from 55 longhand. Then divide the result of that by 3. Keep repeating this process, and come back to us when your result is <=0. :-)

Comment: sure ill do as u said the once i want to divide 55/3 :P. float in ada is kinda wierd and deliver wierd result in simple calculation, as i said below i wrote this to show the problem i have. it show extra zeros

Comment: Nope, there's nothing at all unusual about this. Your compiler uses IEEE standard floating point, just like every other compiler/interpreter you are liable to run across. Try the same loop logic in another language if you don't believe me (or, as I said, try it by hand).

Comment: ah ic ty. thats me being stupid :P . i thought it was awkward why it was working in all cases except this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first printed 0.0 is not zero, it is some fairly large number in float terms, rounded to one decimal place.

No matter how many times you divide by 3, if your arithmetic is accurate, you will never actually get zero this way, so you would have written an infinite loop.

Now, arithmetic in Ada isn't really THAT accurate but for this specific example it apparently rounds in such a way as to give the same effect. Or, as Simon says, you didn't wait long enough. It's not reliable; chances are that `Long_Float` or

```
type Big_Float is digits 18; 
package Big_Float_IO is new Float_IO(Num => Big_Float);
use Big_Float_IO;

number : Big_Float := 55.0;
```

might give different results.

EDIT: On any system employing IEEE P754 floating point arithmetic with a standard-compliant divide instruction, it will eventually exit, unless you have selected a specific optional rounding mode. BUT that still doesn't make it a good way to program!

If your goal is exactly as you described, then re-state it more formally: exit at the first number representing 0.0 when rounded to one decimal place.

That means, any number < 0.05.

So re-write the loop termination as

```
exit when number < 0.05;
```

and be happy.

Otherwise, what is it you are REALLY trying to do?

Comment: ty. am trying to do something else but exit when number < 0.05; works for now the only problem about defining new float is that i get error when i use put or get it say it expect type standard.float  found type big_float

Comment: to solve THAT "problem" you need to instantiate the generic I/O library with your new float type, to create a custom "put" for Big_Float ... I'll edit the answer

Comment: A more appropriate answer might be `exit when number < 0.0001;` or some constant appropriate to your problem : I arrived at 0.05 from your explicit description in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted wouldn't compile; there's no standard operation `&` which takes a `String` on the left and a `Float` on the right, and returns a `String`.

That said, I think you may not have waited long enough: for me, it stops after 99 lines,

```
...
number=  8.40779E-45
number=  2.80260E-45
number=  1.40130E-45
number=  0.00000E+00
```

I wonder why your comparison is `<=`? How could `number` become negative?

Comment: this is not  the code i'm working on. i'm working on something else but i wrote this code to explain the issue

Comment: It may not be the code you're working on, but it is the code you asked about!

Comment: <= because its user variable in the code i have so it will not always be 0 sry for this confusion